# Column 'xxxx' does not belong to underlying table '' error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, dataview

please advise; what is wrong in this code ?
giving below error ... Column 'xxxx' does not belong to underlying table ''.

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FBB-DSL-DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim tablex As New DataTable()

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_columns", conn)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table_name", "tbl_EmpRecords")

                ' get the adapter object and attach the command object to it
                Using ad As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    ' fire Fill method to fetch the data and fill into DataTable
                    ad.Fill(tablex)
                End Using

            End Using
        End Using

        'Creating DataView
        Dim view As New DataView(tablex)
        Dim dt As DataTable = view.ToTable(False, "COLUMN_NAME" )

        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = dt
        CheckBoxList1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The second parameter to _view.ToTable_ should be the name of an existing column of the DataTable _tablex_ Do you have a column with that name in _tablex_?

Comment: Yes Tablex contains a column with this name "xxxx"

Comment: Sorry, but I have no other explanation. Your TableX is filled using the system defined _sp_column_ stored procedure. This stored procedure results in a datatable without a field named 'xxxxx'. What is the real name of the column you are trying to use?

Comment: I'am using the sp_column sp to extract the columns names of the tbl_EmpRecords. Which result 12 columns one of them called EmpUsername and EmpGender . So I filled the tablex then need to filter the results using a datview then assign the final results to cbl.

Comment: So your tablex get back 12 rows. In one of them under the column named COLUMN_NAME there is the word _EmpUserName_ while another row,  for the same column, contains the word _EmpGender_ As you can see you don't have in the tableX datatable a column named _EmpGender or _EmpUserName_ I think my answer below explains the problem

Answer (score 0):

The **system defined** stored procedure **sp_columns** produces a datatable where each row contains the schema details of the columns in the **tbl_EmpRecords**.
This means that the columns present in this **tablex** are the following:

```
TABLE_QUALIFIER, 
TABLE_OWNER,     
TABLE_NAME,      
COLUMN_NAME,     
DATA_TYPE,       
TYPE_NAME,       
PRECISION,       
LENGTH,          
SCALE,           
RADIX, 
NULLABLE, 
SQL_DATA_TYPE, 
SQL_DATETIME_SUB, 
CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH, 
ORDINAL_POSITION, 
IS_NULLABLE, 
SS_DATA_TYPE
```

See the [MSDN docs about sp_columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-columns-transact-sql) for the meaning of each column.

So, there is no column named **XXXXXX** and this is exactly what the error tells you. If you really want to create a new datatable with only one column then your XXXXX field should be one of the above names.

```
' This will return a new table with only one column named COLUMN_NAME'
' The table will contain all the column names of the table tbl_EmpRecords'
Dim dt As DataTable = view.ToTable(False, "COLUMN_NAME")
```

Instead, if you are trying to sort the **tbl_EmpRecords** using someone of the fields defined in that table (IE, empName, HireDate etc....) then you have to use a different approach for your query.

```
   ....
   Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from tbl_EmpRecords", conn)
            Using ad As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                ad.Fill(tablex)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    ....
```

then you can proceed with the DataView code.
However, it is always better to query the database to retrieve only the data you are interested in.
So, if you need only the field XXXXX then just use the query

```
   select XXXXX from tbl_EmpRecords
```

and probably you can ask the database to sort that record for you with

```
   select XXXXX from tbl_EmpRecords ORDER BY XXXXX
```

removing all the DataView code.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but the aim is to extract the column names.

Comment: Added an example to better explain how to extract all the column names of the table _tbl_EmpRecords_

Comment: Thanks, I got your point regarding the _sp_columns_ ..
* I started by filling _dt_ with the _sp_coulmns_ results ..
* Then used the data view to select column 'COLUMN_NAME'; the result was:
`COLUMN_NAME 
TransactionID 
TransactionDate 
TransactionAddedBy 
PerformanceID 
LoginID 
VendorID 
GroupID 
GradeID`
but still didn't find a method to extract the 2 columns (vendorID&GradeID) I need to assign to the cbl only using the _dt.Select_

Comment: I still don't understand what do you expect to see in this cbl ( a combobox?) Can you tell me what is exactly the content expected from this _cbl_?

Comment: I need to fill checkboxlist control with the table needed columns names, then I will create a gridview to extract data upon selection from the checkboxlist options.

Comment: _dt.Select("COLUMN_NAME = 'VendorID' OR COLUMN_NAME = 'GradeID'").ToList()_